# 100% code coverage for simple test

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

Just a simple unit test for code coverage.

```
class Value
{

    protected $v;

    public function __construct($v)
    {
        $this->v = $v;
    }

}

class ValueTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

   /**
    * @covers Value::__construct
    */
    public function test__construct()
    {
        $v = new Value(1);
        $class = new \ReflectionClass($v);
        $property = $class->getProperty('v');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $this->assertSame(1, $property);
    }

}
```

Code Coverage Report:

Summary:
Classes: 100.00% (1/1)
Methods: 100.00% (1/1)
**Lines:   40.00% (2/5)**

Value: Methods: 100.00% ( 1/ 1)   Lines: 100.00% (  2/  2)

Why Lines code coverage measure in summary is not 100%?

Comment: Who cares? The code coverage doesn't show the quality of the code. Focus on testing the class' behaviour, forget about numbers.

Comment: I think code-coverage shows quality of the code, but it can't improve software design

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the Value class from an external file. I tried and got 100% coverage.

Comment: File 'bootstrap.php' in test directory had 3 lines autoloader. So i modified configuration adding: '<filter><blacklist><file>test/bootstrap.php</file></blacklist></filter>' and code coverage increased to 100%